# Не стоит ли сделать [учебное-задание] синонимом недопустимой метки?

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [учебное-задание](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5).

Она:

- Никак не помогает узнать, с чем связан вопрос и к какому разделу языка он относится.
- Имеет 17 вопросов (вручную не удалишь)

Поэтому лучше бы её сделать синонимом недопустимой метки.

Есть ещё метка [школьное-задание](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%88%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). С ней всего 4 вопроса, но лучше бы поступить с неё так же, как и с [учебное-задание](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), чтобы никто её заново не создал.

**Дополнение**:
Эту метку чаще всего используют в тех случаях, когда без неё можно обойтись.
Примеры таких вопросов: [раз](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450168/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%85%d1%83), [два](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/450120/%d0%9e%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) и [три](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449467/%d0%9c%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%8f-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8). Ну и метка провоцирует вопросы "сделай за меня домашку". Если вопрос связан с русским языком, то всегда можно найти другую метку, которая будет лучше описывать тему вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Так вроде бы учебные задания — это нормально, если видно, что человек прикладывает свои усилия и пытается разобраться. Зачем же делать недопустимой? С чем связан вопрос как раз понятно: с каким-то заданием, решение для которого не совсем очевидно. Это устоявшийся жанр.

Comment: Просто метку используют как попало. Да и в 99% случаях её можно заменить другой меткой или вообще убрать из вопроса.

Comment: Если следовать этой логике, то тогда тоже самое про метку л-толстой: она означает, что вопрос связан с затруднением написания слова/предложения из произведения Л. Толстого. Но её же сделали синонимом недопустимой.